# Install Latest windows OS updates is prerequisite for install new Sharepoint Cumulative updates?

Tags: 2013, cumulative-update, windows-server-2012-r2

now our farm configuration database version is **15.0.4753.1000** and before install latest October windows OS updates

1. Do we install latest CU of SharePoint  or
2. Install latest windows updates and install new CU updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above-mentioned methods can be applied with the same result , But the second option is so time wasting because of :

- Microsoft Update/Window Update will install the Sharepoint Security fixes that already included at The Cumulative Update full package.
- The CU will include all previous fix updates whatever it's a security update or functional update between the previous service pack , and the current CU.

So it's a waste time to install SP security update via MU/WU that already included at CU.

**Also, you should check the following important points before applying CU :**

- Don't forget to get a farm backup before applying CU, (you can't do CU rollback)
- Before applying the CU on production , Try to apply it on test farm.
- After installing CU or MU/WU with SharePoint security fixes , you should run the configuration wizard to apply this patch.
- It's preferred to install the CU that will solve a specific issue in your farm,so you should check Improvements and issues that this cumulative update fixes section,  (it's not recommended the latest Update of the current month, it was launched a short time ago , not more people try it).
- The corresponding CU for the current farm build number 15.0.4753.1000 is **Sept 2015** , If you decide to install the CU Full package for the next month October 2015 so the build number should be 15.0.4763.1000.

Comment: thanks ,you mean its not recommend to me to install latest september 2016 CU directly after sept 2015 CU?

Comment: Dear @adilahmed  yes it's not recommended ,because the latest CU was launched a short time ago , not more people try it .so it's not recommended to install it now. meanwhile, you can install it directly from Sept 2015,  but I recommend to install the CU that will solve a specific issue for you as i mentioned above.

Comment: Hi, now we installed new windows updates today  in all production servers , now what sharepoint CU can i go to install or if i not install any updates ( our farm has sept 2015 CU) there is any issue with latest windows updates already installed today

Comment: If you don't have any issue on your farm, I don't recommend to install any CU :) , only try to run the SharePoint configuration wizard on all servers started from the app server that holds the central administration to apply the security fixes that installed via MU/WU . if you have a specific issue try to check which CU will help you at Improvements and issues that this cumulative update fixes section,if your farm is stable and you also need to install CU , try to install the next or CU = current CU + 3 month that is Dec 2015 . Note : must have a backup there's not roll back , there is outage

Answer (score 0):

If and when you are planning to do the two steps anyway, it's just plain better practice to have the server ready before you start to update a component on the server. Ensure that there are no pending restarts before you start to install the SharePoint's CU.