# Best practices / steps to follow while installing windows critical updates on SharePoint 2013 farm as part of organization policy

Tags: 2013

Please help me with the best practices / steps to follow while installing windows critical updates on SharePoint 2013 farm as part of organization policy (OS - windows server 2012)

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows update enabled , and the windows update has been installed on all SharePoint servers within the farm based on your organization policy ,

The only thing you need to plan is to run the `Sharepoint configuration wizard` on all Sharepoint server started from the application server that holds the Central administration , to apply the **Security fixes** that included at this M/W update .

**Note :** SharePoint 2013 allow to continue execution without PSCONFIG after installing fixes.so you can schedule running configuration wizard after M/W update is finished.

Check also

- [Install Latest windows OS updates is prerequisite for install new Sharepoint Cumulative updates?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196089/install-latest-windows-os-updates-is-prerequisite-for-install-new-sharepoint-cum/196102#196102)
- [SharePoint CUs and Windows Update – Important Update!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/02/26/sharepoint-cus-and-windows-update-important-update/)